# QuickFIX/J - Output Logs to Text File/Console

Tags: quickfixj

I am trying to output the console messages received by 'fromApp' to a TextArea in my Swing GUI. I am trying to direct pricing logs that I am pulling. Is there a way I can direct these logs (maybe as a String) to a variable or Text file etc? This is my fromApp:

```
public void fromApp(quickfix.Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound,
IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {
}
```

Any ideas let me know! Thanks

Comment: Worked with this some years ago.  As i rember it, there is a special Log class that does this

Comment: This is controlled by the kind of `LogFactory` that you use in your application. E.g. there is a `FileLogFactory` or a `ScreenLogFactory`.